# Whats the error in the following MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON MYTABLE 
FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
       IF break < 0 THEN 
          SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' 
          set message_text = 'ERROR';
       END IF;
   END;
```

This throws a syntax error and I'm not able to find it.

Comment: This code shows a syntax error and i am not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the delimiter that MySQL is using as an end-of-line marker. You need to do this for `CREATE TRIGGER` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` because if you don't MySQL will treat the first semi-colon as the end of the command and finish processing it prematurely - hence the syntax error.

Do this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON MYTABLE 
FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
       IF break < 0 THEN 
          SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' 
          set message_text = 'ERROR';
       END IF;
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now, MySQL will continue processing your `CREATE TRIGGER` command until it reaches `$$`, and include the semi-colons as part of the trigger script. Note that I've set the delimiter back to semicolon when I'm finished.